# Calculate exchange rate

Tags: tokens, exchanges

I am running am ethereum node and I'd like to calculate the exchange rate of any token into USD, without using any external API. How do i accomplish this?

Comment: What kind of node? An Ethereum node? If yes, there is no way to know information from the outside world from within the blockchain, unless you're using an [oracle](https://docs.ethhub.io/built-on-ethereum/oracles/what-are-oracles/) - which usually requires trust.

Comment: Yes, an ethereum node. So basicay there is no way calculating the price, as listed here https://etherscan.io/tokens without using oracles?

Comment: No, it's not possible without oracles. Take a look at [ChainLink](https://feeds.chain.link/) and the [Compound Open Price Feed](https://compound.finance/docs/prices).